# General rule of thumb for deciding functions of two variables are continuous or have limits

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Is there any particular strategy to determine whether for sure a function of two variables or perhaps three is continuous or necessarily has a limit.? For example the function $f(x,y)=\frac{x^3y^2}{x^4+y^4}$ if $ \textbf{x}\neq 0$ and $0$ if $\textbf{x}=0$ is continuous, but what is a good strategy to figure this out efficiently?

Generally the way I approach this is to try and find two sequences $\{(x_n,y_n)\}$,$\{(w_n,z_n)\}$ approaching $(0,0)$. Then if I cannot find the function applied to these sequences converging to different limits I try to prove the result by finding an upper bound on $f$. What is an easier/ more efficient strategy for doing this?

Comment: If you're asking for a non-rigorous approach, what I usually do is graph cross-sections and see if that looks continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(X,d_{X})$ and $(Y,d_{Y})$ be metric spaces, $f:X\to Y$ a function, $E\subseteq X$ s.t. $x_{0}\in X$ is an adherent point of $E$ and $L\in Y$. We say that $f$ approaches $L$ as $x$ approaches $x_{0}$ along $E$ iff for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there corresponds $\delta_{\varepsilon} > 0$ such that for every $x\in E$ we have that
\begin{align*}
d_{X}(x,x_{0}) < \delta_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow d_{Y}(f(x),L) < \varepsilon
\end{align*}

Based on such context, there is an additional result which states when $f$ has limit $L$. More precisely, the following two statements are logically equivalent:

1. The limit of $f$ is $L$ when $x$ approaches $x_{0}$ along $E$.
2. Whenever $x_{n}$ is a sequence of points in $E$ which converges to $x_{0}$, the sequence $f(x_{n})$ converges to $L$.

Based on such result, you can test whether or not a function between metric spaces converges.

Hopefully this helps!